# What is the correct translation for "Am I really alive?"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

It's supposed to be a genuine question a character asks himself after waking from a dream.
I've tried different online translators but I'm not sure if I can trust them. Any help would be nice.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you edit your question to elaborate on what you want that phrase to mean? Context can make a huge difference, so we can't often just translate. (To add information, please edit the question instead of writing comments.)

Answer (score 7):

While @FlatAssembler is correct that that's one way someone could say "Am I really alive?" it might not necessarily be the most idiomatic way.

If what you're looking for is an expression of surprise—like, "Holy moley, I can't believe I'm alive!"—then what you want is an accusative of exclamation: *Mene vivam?* if your character is female and *Mene vivum?* if your character isn't. That means essentially "Me, living?" and there's an implied *esse* ("be"). You could also do *Mene vivere?" which is "Me, live?" The "really" is left out of the literal translation, but it's communicated by the word endings, which in this case can imply a sense of amazement.

If what you want is a genuine inquiry by somebody trying to find out if they're alive rather than dead, you'd probably use the fairly general verb *vivere*: *Verene vivo?*

If what you want is a genuine inquiry by somebody or something trying to find out if she/it is animate rather than inanimate, you'd say *Verene sum animans?* which means, pretty literally, "Am I animate?" but which in Latin doesn't have the same kind of technical connotation.

Comment: Great to see you back on the site!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is "*Sumne ego vere vivus?*" if the speaker is male (or non-binary) and "*Sumne ego vere viva?*" if the speaker is female.

Comment: But whats the difference between "Sumne ego vere vivus?" and "Egone vere vivit?"? Is it just more correct?

Comment: @CarlosAnti *Egone vere vivit* is ungrammatical. You could go with *Egone vero vivo* or *Vivone vero*. Hopefully the differences will be discussed here or in another answer.